# Equivalence of $\forall x P(x) \lor\forall x Q(x)$ and $\forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

What are examples of predicates $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ and domains where the above two statements are equivalent?

My stab at the problem:

Let the domain of discourse be all positive whole numbers, $P(x)$ be defined as "$x \geq 0$, and $Q(x)$ be defined as $x + 1 \geq 0$. In this case, both the first statement and the second would evaluate to true... however, I don't know if this proves equivalency, because I don't think I can say that two statements are equivalent just because they both happen to evaluate to true.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: initially had $\land$'s when I should have had $\lor$'s...

Comment: Erm if you change the question completely, you should at least inform those who answered your questions otherwise how would we know...

Answer (score 1):

The two statements **using $\land$, as in your original question**, are equivalent, so for every model (a domain, and interpretations of $P$ and $Q$ in that domain), both are true or both are false. This is because either statement is true if and only if the interpretations of both $P$ and $Q$ equal the entire domain.

Your "Let the domain of discourse..." paragraph doesn't prove anything in general, it just gives an example of two predicates $P,Q$ whose interpretations are the same *in that model*.

Now you've changed the question to ask about $\lor$, and the answer is very different: the two statements are not equivalent. 
$$
\forall x \, P(x) \lor \forall x \, Q(x) \tag{1}
$$
is true when (and only when) either $P$ is interpreted as the entire domain, or $Q$ is. However,
$$
\forall x \, (P(x) \lor Q(x)) \tag{2}
$$
is true in a model $M$ iff for every element $a$ of the universe of $M$ (the *domain*, in your usage), either $a\in P^M$ or $a\in Q^M$, where the superscripted predicate symbols are the interpretations in $M$ of those symbols. (1) implies (2), but (2) does not imply (1). A simple example: let $M$ be the integers, and interpret $P$ and $Q$ as the even and the odd integers respectively. Obviously (2) holds — every integer is either even or odd — but just as obviously (1) is false: it's not true that every integer is even, or every integer is odd.

Comment: It's wrong to say $P$ "equals the entire domain". $P$ is a predicate and cannot equal a domain.

Comment: Well, thanks for the pedantry. Obviously I meant "the interpretation $P^M$ of $P$ in such a model $M$" and so on. But I emended the language to be more precise.

Comment: No I wasn't even being pedantic about the distinction between the predicate symbol and the predicate itself. My point is that even the interpretation is NOT a collection! A predicate is a **relation**, not a collection. There is a correspondence between $1$-place predicates and subsets of the domain, but they are NOT the same. It is not good to confuse things like that, especially when we are in fact talking about a **formalization** of logic!

Comment: Sorry but I downvoted; I'll remove it if you fix the error. (Note that the asker has changed her question as well.)

Comment: I only downvoted for the error of identifying predicates with the subset of the domain of the structure. I feel it is very important (especially when studying or teaching logic) to be precise and distinguish between objects that are different, whether or not there is a correspondence. You cannot for example say that a set in ZFC is an indicator function on the set-theoretic universe, since any such function is too big to be a set and hence cannot be a function (as encoded in ZFC).

Comment: You mean the "error" resulting from answering the original question? Do you see the word "collection" anywhere in my answer? It seems you're using "relation" to mean part of the formal language, whereas most mathematicians use it to mean an extensional thing, a set of ordered pairs in the typical case, or a set of n-tuples as in "n-ary relation". Such a thing can be an interpretation of a predicate symbol, or the set of all n-tuples of a model that satisfy a formula. ¶ Finally, I don't need a lecture about the purpose and value of formalization, thank you.

Comment: There is no such identification, or casual abuse of terminology, in the answer as it now stands. It does still answer the original question, which I'll now fix.

Comment: Did you read my initial comment? I said that it is wrong to say that $P$ is equal to the domain. The domain is a collection in the meta-system, and hence by saying that you are indeed saying that the **predicate** $P$ is a **collection** (a set, if your meta-system is ZFC).

Comment: You wrote exactly "[...] unless (the interpretations of) both $P$ and $Q$  equal the entire domain.", which **is an identification of predicates with sets**, contrary to your last comment.

Comment: Overly casual usage. Please, I've had more than enough of this pedantry and going on about an answer that doesn't exist anymore. You can have the last word if you want it, I will not reply.

Comment: That's up to you. I've seen too many students who cannot understand logic simply because it's not explained precisely. Correspondences that you and I understand are not always clear to beginners. The only thing I don't understand is why you insist on not changing your phrasing just so slightly to make it correct, for example "unless $P,Q$ are true on the entire domain".

Comment: Oh, that's what's still rubbing -- not enough that it's preceded by "(the interpretations of)", huh. OK I'll remove the parens.... There, I removed them. Happy now?

Comment: Okay I think we have different interpretations of the word "interpretation". The convention in logic is that the interpretation of a predicate symbol is a relation in the meta-system, not a collection. That is why I kept talking about identification between collections and predicates. Is that it? That's why I suggested changing "equal to" to "true on".

Comment: But maybe it's not as universal a convention as I thought. I'll assume that's the issue so I'm sorry and I've removed the downvote.

Comment: Again, I never used the word "collection". But no matter. Thanks for the un-downvote.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand you then. Is the domain a **collection** in your meta-system or not? If so, then for an interpretation of a predicate symbol to be **equal to** the domain, it has to be the same collection. If not, then what is the meaning of "domain"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38132/discussion-between-user21820-and-briano).

Comment: Really sorry about this but I only just saw your reply when randomly browsing through my past chat-rooms. I see that you were using a specific implementation of "interpretation" of a predicate-symbol. In particular, you defined unary relations on $U$ as subsets of $U$, although I would (pedantically) define them as subsets of $U^1$. I'll gladly delete all my prior comments if you wish. Just in case you didn't know, to notify another participant in a chat-room or comment thread, you've to include `@username` somewhere in your message; that's why I didn't know you had replied. =)

Answer (score 1):

"Equivalent" does mean "have the same truth value". So if you have shown that two sentences have the same truth value in some model (some domain plus some interpretation of the predicate symbols and function symbols), as you have done, then the two sentences are equivalent.

Furthermore, as long as you make $P(a)$ true for any $a$ in your model, then it does not matter what $Q$ is, since both sentences would be true.

**[The following answers the original question, which has been changed...]**

Also, note that the two sentences in your question are always equivalent in any model. You can check this by expanding the definitions. Take any model $M$. Then "$\forall x\ ( P(x) )$" is true in $M$ iff "$P(a)$" is true for any element $a$ in $M$. Likewise for "$\forall x\ ( Q(x) )$". If you have both, then "$P(a) \land Q(a)$" is true for any element $a$ in $M$, and hence "$\forall x\ ( P(x) \land Q(x) )$" is true in $M$. Similar reasoning shows the converse.